# What is the component responsible for fetching the image from the image registry in the Kubernetes worker node?

Tags: kubernetes

"Does the kubelet or the container runtime take responsibility for pulling the container image from the container registry, considering that the kubelet uses the container runtime to run the container?"

I checked documentations but I could not find anything specific.

Answer (score 0):

From Kubernetes official docs:

> By default, kubelet pulls images serially. In other words, kubelet
> sends only one image pull request to the image service at a time.
> Other image pull requests have to wait until the one being processed
> is complete.

Further info [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#serial-and-parallel-image-pulls)

Comment: you are welcome appreciate if you can mark the answer as valid :) thanks !